# How do I disable the animated box appearing in my Google search results?

Tags: google-search

How do I disable the animated box appearing in my Google search results?

Here is a screenshot of the box titled "People also search for":

[image]

The problem with it is that it is animated and moves other parts of the page around. I was trying to click the ProjectE link and it was moved out the way and I clicked on the wrong link (something from the box instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use web browser add-ons and user scripts you could use one of them to disable *CSS transitions* on Google search result pages. Other options are to ignore the box and close it.

The above because Google Search settings doesn't include a way to disable features like this. It might be part of a *A/B test* and/or it might be controlled by the *personalized Google experience* algorithms.

*A/B tests* are conducted on the Google Search result page by Google data scientists to test slight changes.

*Personalized Google experience* uses data collected by different means i.e. Google Account search history, user location, etc. to rank page results and present some search results page features.

---

On CSS terminology, the effect is called *transition*; *animation* refers to other thing.

Resources

- [The A/B Test: Inside the Technology That's Changing the Rules of Business | Wired](https://www.wired.com/2012/04/ff-abtesting/)
- [Google Personalized Search | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Personalized_Search)
- [Userscript | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript)
- [transition | Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)
- [animation | Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)
- [See & control your Web & App Activity | Google Websearch Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/54068?hl=en)