# Disabling the Google suggestions which appear below the website I clicked on

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

Since some days ago Google changed its way to show search's results; in particular, when you do a research, you get a list of websites:

[image]

If I click on a website and then I go back to the webpage of results or I open a website in another tab, I get a list of new websites below like this:

[image]

How can I avoid this annoying view?

If I click on "Hide These Results", it works only for one time; indeed, if I click on another link, Google will suggest again new websites below.

Comment: The second image shows "Hide These Results". Try clicking that button. If that doesn't work, the page shows other buttons, i.e. at the right of `https://gearpatrol.com > Tech > Product Support` there is a More button (the three dots aligned vertical). Also at the bottom of the page there is a Help link. Please research, share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please bear in mind that not all users are able to see what you are seeing, even following the same steps (I can't see what you are showing in your images). Any detail that you consider relavant, please [edit] the question to include it on the question body as comments  might be hidden or removed.

Comment: Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154448/88163

Comment: @Rubén my question is different because now there are additional suggestions (plus the classic ones showed in the picture of your hyperlink)